# What is the result or equivalent order of this infinite sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

As described by the title, can we obtain an analytical result for the following infinite sum or provide an equivalent order as $p \rightarrow 1$?
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{p^j}{1-p^j}\right)^{i+1},i\ \text{is non-negative integer}.
$$
Now, I only know that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{p^j}{1-p^j}\approx \frac{1}{1-p}\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right).$$
I often have to compute the sum of infinite series in my research. I really appreciate if one can provide a textbook or useful handbook to reference.

Comment: What is $i$? Is it an integer? Does it help to write $\frac{p^j}{1-p^j}$ as $\frac{1}{1-p^j}-1$ and apply the binomial theorem? ETA: Oh, that looks like you end up with infinities. Hmm, let me think about that.

Answer (score 4):

If a heuristic consideration is acceptable, we can do the following.

Let's denote $\epsilon=1-p \,(p<1)$, and $$ S(n, \epsilon)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{p^k}{1-p^k}\right)^n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{nk\ln(1-\epsilon)}}{(1-e^{k\ln(1-\epsilon)})^n}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{nk\ln(1-\epsilon)}(1-e^{k\ln(1-\epsilon)})^{-n}$$
We consider the case of $n\epsilon\ll1$, and $n>2$ (is not necessarily an integer).
When $k$ is growing, the nominator is decreasing, and the denominator - increasing. At $\,k\epsilon =\ln2 \,\,(k=\frac{\ln2}{\epsilon}) \,\,\frac{p^k}{1-p^k}=1$, and the main contribution to the sum comes from the terms with $k\ll\frac{\ln2}{\epsilon}$.

Bearing this in mind, we can use the following approximation:
$$e^{nk\ln(1-\epsilon)}\approx e^{-nk\epsilon}\tag{1}$$
$$(1-e^{k\ln(1-\epsilon)})^{-n}\approx(1-e^{-k\epsilon-\frac{k\epsilon^2}{2}})^{-n}\approx\left(k\epsilon-\frac{k^2\epsilon^2}{2}+\frac{k\epsilon^2}{2}\right)^{-n}$$
$$=(k\epsilon)^{-n}\left(1-\frac{k\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)^{-n}\approx (k\epsilon)^{-n}e^{-n\ln\left(1-\frac{k\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)}\approx(k\epsilon)^{-n}e^{-\frac{n\epsilon}{2}}e^{\frac{nk\epsilon}{2}}\tag{2}$$
and our sum looks like
$$S(\epsilon, n)\approx\frac{e^{-\frac{n\epsilon}{2}}}{\epsilon^n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\frac{-nk\epsilon}{2}}}{k^n}=\frac{e^{-\frac{n\epsilon}{2}}}{\epsilon^n}\operatorname{Li}_n\left(e^{\frac{-nk\epsilon}{2}}\right)\tag{3}$$
Using the representation $\displaystyle \frac{1}{k^n}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-kt}$ and performing summation with respect to $k$,
$$S(\epsilon, n)\approx\frac{e^{-n\epsilon}}{\epsilon^n}\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{n-1}}{e^t-e^{-\frac{nk\epsilon}{2}}}dt\approx\frac{1-n\epsilon}{\epsilon^n}\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{n-1}}{e^t-1+\frac{n\epsilon}{2}}dt\tag{4}$$
The integral we evaluate in the following way:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{n-1}}{e^t-1+\frac{n\epsilon}{2}}dt=\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}+\frac{1}{e^t-1+\frac{n\epsilon}{2}}-\frac{1}{e^t-1}\right)dt$$
$$=\Gamma(n)\zeta(n)-\frac{n\epsilon}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{n-1}}{(e^t-1)(e^t-1+\frac{n\epsilon}{2})}dt$$
As we suppose $n>2$, the second integral converges at $n\epsilon=0$ in the denominator. Therefore, keeping only the terms up to $\sim n\epsilon$, we can write
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{n-1}}{e^t-1+\frac{n\epsilon}{2}}dt\approx\Gamma(n)\zeta(n)-\frac{n\epsilon}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{n-1}}{(e^t-1)^2}dt$$
$$=\Gamma(n)\zeta(n)-\frac{n\epsilon}{2}\Gamma(n)\big(\zeta(n-1)-\zeta(n)\big)\tag{5}$$
Putting (5) int0 (4), with the required accuracy
$$\boxed{\,\,S(\epsilon, n)\approx\frac{\zeta(n)}{\epsilon^n}-\frac{n}{2\,\epsilon^{n-1}}\big(\zeta(n-1)+\zeta(n)\big)=\frac{\zeta(n)}{(1-p)^n}-\frac{n}{2\,(1-p)^{n-1}}\big(\zeta(n-1)+\zeta(n)\big)\,\,}$$

---

Now, we can make a numeric check with WolframAlpha (we keep in mind that it is supposed that $n\epsilon\ll1$):

$\displaystyle n=5\,\epsilon =0.1\quad\text{exact}=60 632;\,\text{approx}\approx 50712$

$\displaystyle n=3\,\epsilon =0.01\quad\text{exact}=1.1602 \times 10^6;\,\text{approx}\approx 1.1593 \times 10^6$

$\displaystyle n=2.6\,\epsilon =0.01\quad\text{exact}=199855;\,\text{approx}\approx 199505$

$\displaystyle n=5\,\epsilon =0.01\quad\text{exact}=9.8504 \times 10^9;\,\text{approx}\approx 9.8395 \times 10^9$

$\displaystyle n=2.6\,\epsilon =0.001\quad\text{exact}=8.20777 \times 10^7;\,\text{approx}\approx 8.20755 \times 10^7$

Comment: Cool! Aesthetics of violence.